# Computed-property + ViewModifier preventing Button tap

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to change my `Button`'s background color via a `ViewModifier` as the color styles can be complex.
I have a computed property that listens to my `@State` variable that then updates the `ViewModifier`.

To do this, I created a custom `ButtonStyle` that executes a closure when the `configuration.isPressed` property changes. This works but the more I tap the button's text, the less the action gets executed. It's like something is blocking the action from running.

```
enum ButtonState: String {
    case `default`, pressed
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var buttonState: ButtonState = .default

    var buttonBackgroundColor: Color? {
        switch buttonState {
        case .pressed:
            return Color.green
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            print("Tap Detected")
            print("---")
        } label: {
            HStack {
                Text("Tap Me")
            }
            .frame(width: 300, height: 150)
            .applyBGModifier(color: buttonBackgroundColor)
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
        }
        .buttonStyle(ButtonStateStyle(didChangePressState: { isPressed in
            updateButtonState(isPressed: isPressed)
        }))
    }

    private func updateButtonState(isPressed: Bool) {
        if isPressed {
            buttonState = .pressed
        } else {
            buttonState = .default
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct ButtonStateStyle: ButtonStyle {
    var didChangePressState: (Bool) -> Void

    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .onChange(of: configuration.isPressed) { isPressed in
                print("detected configuration isPressed \(isPressed)")
                didChangePressState(isPressed)
            }
    }
}

struct BackgroundColorModifier: ViewModifier {
    var backgroundColor: Color?

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if let backgroundColor {
            content.background(backgroundColor)
        } else {
            content.background(Color.yellow)
        }
    }
}

extension View {
    func applyBGModifier(color: Color?) -> some View {
        modifier(BackgroundColorModifier(backgroundColor: color))
    }
}
```

I've updated `contentShape` to no avail. This works if I don't use `ViewModifier` but I have to in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In the given code, the onChange modifier is being called twice because there are two sources triggering the change in the isPressed state.

The first source is the Button itself, which triggers the change when it's pressed and released. The second source is the ButtonStateStyle modifier, which also triggers the change when it detects a change in the isPressed state.

to prevent this issue, you can use gesture modifier:

```
struct ButtonStateStyle: ButtonStyle {

    var didChangePressState: (Bool) -> Void

func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
    configuration.label
        .gesture(
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                .onChanged { _ in
                    didChangePressState(true)
                }
                .onEnded { _ in
                    didChangePressState(false)
                }
        )
    }
}
```